# Загрузка файла со своим именем

Tags: php

При создании нового пользователя, по архитектуре сайта фото пользователя выводиться как **id.jpg**
Подскажите как при загрузке сделать так, что бы имя файла менялось на новый id

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", $link);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$id_name = ($result[0] + 1);
}
```

$id_name = допустим **3**

*Добавление фото*

```
<form name="uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    Отправить этот файл: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Загрузить</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("form[name='uploader']").submit(function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'file.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert('Ошибка!');
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

file.php

```
$uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'img'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $out = "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
} else {
    $out = "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
}

echo $out;
```

За ранее спасибо!)

Comment: `$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $id_name . '.jpg';` кажется так

Comment: Огромное спасибо!) Работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $id_name . '.jpg';
```

Спасибо автору Artem Gorlachev